# I having problem in my sudoku code its shows error

Tags: java, runtime-error, sudoku

In my sudoku code my boolean return true value but it does not stop running, It doesn't give me right answer.

my code dost does not give any value if it is true, not show an error or something else but if the code return false then it gives me the correct answer.

I want to know what happens in my code

````
    public static boolean isSafe(int sudoku[][], int row, int col, int digit) {
        // row
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            if (sudoku[i][col] == digit) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        // column
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            if (sudoku[row][j] == digit) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        // grid
        int startRow = (row / 3) * 3;
        int startCol = (col / 3) * 3;

        // 3 X 3 grid
        for (int i = startRow; i < startRow + 3; i++) {
            for (int j = startCol; j < startCol + 3; j++) {
                if (sudoku[i][j] == digit) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    public static boolean sudokuSolver(int sudoku[][], int row, int col) {
        // Base case
        if (row == 9) {
            return true;
        }

        // recursion
        int nextRow = row;
        int nextCol = col+1;

        if (col+1 == 9) {
            nextRow = row+1;
            nextCol = 0;
        }

        // check place value is zero or somethingelse
        if (sudoku[row][col] != 0) {
            sudokuSolver(sudoku, nextRow, nextCol);
        }

        // placement of digit
        for (int digit = 1; digit <= 9; digit++) {
            if (isSafe(sudoku, row, col, digit)) {
                sudoku[row][col] = digit;
                if (sudokuSolver(sudoku, nextRow, nextCol)) {
                    return true;
                }
                sudoku[row][col] = 0;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public static void printSudoku(int sudoku[][]) {
        System.out.println("----- SUDOKU ----");
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
                System.out.print(sudoku[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int sudoku[][] = { { 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                { 4, 9, 0, 1, 5, 7, 0, 0, 2 },
                { 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 4, 1, 9, 0 },
                { 1, 8, 5, 0, 6, 0, 0, 2, 0 },
                { 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 6, 0 },
                { 9, 6, 0, 4, 0, 5, 3, 0, 0 },
                { 0, 3, 0, 0, 7, 2, 0, 0, 4 },
                { 0, 4, 9, 0, 3, 0, 0, 5, 7 },
                { 8, 2, 7, 0, 0, 9, 0, 1, 3 }, };

        if (sudokuSolver(sudoku, 0, 0)) {
            System.out.println("Solution exist");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Solution not exist");
        }
    }
} ```
````

Comment: I suspect you might just be underestimating how much 81^81 is. Sudoku is notoriously difficult to solve. Brute force does not work well here.

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger? That might be a way to see wether the code is doing what you expect or something else entirely. I dont know what you use for development, but here is a guide to debugging for IntelliJ in case thats what you use: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/debugging-your-first-java-application.html .